# Weird error when concatenating Series data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text, concatenation, corpus

I have a bunch of dataframes with rows of text data. I imported a single column from each dataframe and appended them to a list like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = 'filepath' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df['body'])
```

Now I am trying to create a corpus of documents, so I want to concatenate/merge/join (not sure which is a better approach) all the rows, so that each column becomes a single cell. So each element in the list should be a cell instead of rows of cells.

When I concatenate a single element in the list, it does what I want. For instance,

```
li[0].str.cat(sep = "")
```

creates a single cell of text.

However, when I loop through the list like so:

```
corpus = []

for i in li:
    corpus.append(li[i].str.cat(sep = ""))
```

I get the following error:

```
----> 4     corpus.append(li[i].str.cat(sep = ""))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series
```

I'm sure the problem is simple, but I haven't seen an answer posted here for this issue, and I do not know why this error occurs (since str.cat should work for Series data). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `corpus.append(i.str.cat(sep=""))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just have the wrong expectations about how the for loop syntax works:

```
for i in li:
    corpus.append(li[i].str.cat(sep = ""))
```

When you use the syntax `for __ in __`, you should read this as `for item in list` not `for index in list`.

Since `i` is already the item itself, not the index, it doesn't work to try to use `i` to index into `li` (where you've written `li[i]`). This is why you're getting an error about "list indices".

Thus, this should work for you:

```
for i in li:
    corpus.append(i.str.cat(sep = ""))
```

As a side note, I'd recommend using a variable other than `i` to avoid this confusion - maybe `e` for element, or better yet (IMO), just spell out exactly what the element is.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your approach will concatenate all of the rows across all of the dataframes. If I have 10 dataframes with 100 rows each, I will get one element in the list. However, I want to concatenate each dataframe separately, so I want 10 elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what you're saying - but I don't see how it would change the fact that you can't index into a list using an item in that list. Do you understand my point about how the for loop works in python? If you want to iterate over both the indices and elements in a list, you could try ```for i, element in enumerate(li): ...```

Comment: Say I have 10 dataframes, each with 10 rows. I want to make 10 dataframes in which their respective rows are combined (i.e., 10 dataframes, each with 1 row). Then, I want to append the new dataframes to a list.The code you have provided combines all the rows across all the dataframes (i.e., there is 1 dataframe with 1 row). Truly sorry if this is confusing, I greatly appreciate your help!